# Use VBA ( ADODB) in MSAccess to append data from remote DB to a local table with out locking records in the remote DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, adodb

What I'm trying to do is seperate my existing MS Access application into a front-end (which will run locally on a user's machine) and backend (which will be hosted on a networked file server) and allow users to choose between "read-only" and "write" modes. The idea is that only one user can use the "write" mode at a time, thus preventing the same piece of inventory being allocated to mutliple customers.  My problem is that the application currently handles concurrency by requiring users to open a .bat file which only allows them to enter application if a .ldb file does not already exist (there is no read-only mode currently), so I need to prevent users accessing the production data in "read-only" mode from creating a .ldb file and unessarily blocking out other users.

The biggest challenge to implemnting this is that users must have write access to the temporary tables in the MS Access (.mdb) file installed locally. I have tried to implement this using a linked table, but I'm not sure how I can control when records become locked using linked tables (which creates a .ldb file).

Answer (score 1):

You could change the sharing setting back to Exclusive Mode. Then only one person can access the file at a time. Check out this link and the other sharing options you have.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-options-for-a-shared-access-database-mdb-HP005188297.aspx

*Side note*: Yikes. Using Access in a shared network environment is not fun. I hope nothing important/time sensitive/secure is in this file. The .ldb file not being deleted and blocking other users is something that I use to see happen regularly in this situation. I believe splitting the Access file into a front-end and back-end like you've done is the first step. Then using linked tables to a SQL Server database can help resolve these issues. But if you're going to this level of effort you may want to consider dumping Access and get a COTS product or create a new application.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Access you are using, theres alot of flexibility in the UI developement.  In other words, this sounds more like an "interface" issue as apposed to a "database" issue.  Given everybody is able write to a table, you should be able to check in somewhat real time (performance can be an issue with larger datasets), whether a particular has been added to inventory or not.

They I handled this problem is have two tables, an incomming and outgoing log, and set up a query that did the math against the inventory list on the amount of products.  And like a general ledger, select set amount of time to "close the log" (monthly, quarterly) so that the query is not taking into account stuff that happened two years ago.

If you need more help with Access related stuff, [Access Monster](http://www.accessmoster.com/) is a good forum site that deal with nothing but access.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that the application currently handles concurrency by requiring users to open a .bat file which only allows them to enter application if a .ldb file does not already exist (there is no read-only mode currently), so I need to prevent users accessing the production data in "read-only" mode from creating a .ldb file and unessarily blocking out other users.

--> If every user has his own copy of the front-end on his own machine, you'd have to check the .ldb file of the **back-end**.

I guess it would be easier to give everyone write access to the backend and manage the actual writing programmatically with a "locked by User X" field in the backend:

You said:

> preventing the same piece of inventory being allocated to mutliple customers

1. If this is the only reason for putting all users but one in read-only mode, you could put a "locked by User X" field on the inventory table. If someone starts to modify (or even opens) a piece of inventory, update the record with his user name, and delete the user name again when he's done.
   If another user tries to open the same piece of inventory as well, the name of the first user will already be in the "locked by User X" field, so you can put the second user in read-only mode.
2. If the inventory pieces are not the only problem and all the other users really are not allowed to change **anything** as soon as someone else already is editing, you can create a new table with only one column and one row and use this as the "locked by User X" field. As soon as there is a user name inside, you can put everyone else in readonly mode.

No matter how you do it, you will have to provide some kind of admin menu, so if someone's front-end crashes while editing, someone else needs to be able to unlock this user's locked data (=delete his username from the "locked by User X" field).